# Looping an IDW function in R

Tags: r, loops, kriging

I am kind of new to R and I would like to test different parameters to perform an Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) interpolation.

```
data.idw.n <- idw(variable~1, data, data.grid, nmax=n)
```

I would like to repeat the following function several times, by just changing the `n` value (let's say from `1` to `20`) of the `nmax` variable and store the results separately to perform a model sensibility analysis.

I think i would need some kind of basic looping. Can someone help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: How about `list.idw <- lapply(1:20, function(n) idw(variable~1, data, data.grid, nmax=n))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would use `mapply`:

```
list_of_idw_results = mapply(idw, 
                             nmax = 1:20, 
                             MoreArgs = list(formula = variable ~ 1, 
                                             data = data, 
                                             newdata = data.grid))
```

This leads to a list of `idw` results, for `nmax` values from 1 to 20. You can vary more variables at the same time by adding more variables after `nmax = 20`.

Comment: Also a great solution! I will have to look into it! Thank you!